# MVC website CORS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cors

I have a button on a view page , which on button click does a postback. My question is do I have to implement CORS for this scenario ? Does it come under single origin policy ?

Here is the code in my js file

```
$('#submitBtn').click(function () {
            form.action = '/go/signin';
            form.submit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is all on the same domain name, there's no need to dabble in CORS.

Answer (score 0):

If it's in the same domain, you don't need to handle CORS; CORS is only when you are making requests outside of your domain.  See [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) for excellent overviews.